# Problema na classe dict e ao unir grande quantidade de elementos por dict em Python

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Olá, estou tendo problemas com `dict`. Tenho duas listas: `lista1` e `lista2`, ambas do mesmo tamanho. Quando executo o comando: `dicionario = dict(zip(lista1, lista2))` produz um dicionário "menor" do que o tamanho da lista. Fiz muitos testes e realmente é isso a ocorrer. Em cada loop fiz um print do tamanho de `lista1` e `lista2` e elas sempre tem o mesmo tamanho. Separei as operações de `zip` e `dict` e sempre fiz print de ambas. Resultado: o `dict` não está a concatenar de forma correta. Vale lembrar que as chaves para meu `dict` são `double` e os `values` são listas de listas (ou seja, `lista1 = 52.84` e `lista2 = [[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 4],[5, 6, 7]]` por exemplo). O fato de ser uma grande quantidade de dados pode influenciar? Nesse caso cada lista possui 100 posições, como eu disse. A `lista1` é uma lista de 100 posições composta de valores `double` e a `lista2` é uma lista de listas (`lista2 = [list1, list2, list3, ..., list_100]`) que possui 100 posições e cada elemento `[list1, list2, list3, ..., list_100]` etc. possui tamanho 80. Consegui explicar? Ajuda urgente haha

Comment: É possível que o suposto resultado (dict) tenha chaves iguais, logo só a última chave/valor é considerada

Answer (score 0):

Allan,

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) da função zip:

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

Logo, deve existir algum erro na validação dos seus dados que não está conseguindo identificar que uma das listas é menor que a outra. Quanto ao tamanho dos dados, repliquei o seu problema utilizando listas 100 vezes maiores para demonstrar que não há problemas.

```
# Criamos a lista de floats com 10000 posições
lista1 = list(np.random.random_sample(10000))
print(len(lista1) == 10000)
True

# Segunda lista de 10000 listas com 8000 posições cada.
lista2 = [[' '] * 8000 for x in range(0, 10000)]
print(len(lista2) == 10000)
True
print(all([len(x) == 8000 for x in lista2]) == True)
True

# Geramos o dicionário
dicionario = dict(zip(lista1, lista2))
print(len(dicionario) == 10000)
True

# Validamos os dados
print(all([len(y) == 8000 for x, y in dicionario.items()]))
True
```

Desta forma validamos a obtenção de um dicionário com 10000 chaves, cada uma correspondendo a uma lista de 8000 posições.